# How to concatenate strings at assembly time (using CATSTR?)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have multiple build configurations of a project, and they each need to have some globally defined strings. These strings should really be built at assembly time by concatenating a root and a config-specific suffix, for example, I might have the root "TABLE" and config A would use the suffix "ALPHA" and config "B" would use the suffix "BETA", so when I build A, I end up with my globally defined string having the value "TABLEALPHA" and for B, the value "TABLEBETA"

Ideally, the suffix is provided via the command line, via a /D type definition.

A complication is that we use a proprietary source language that first "compiles" to MASM then uses MASM to assemble. Which makes it hard to provide good sample code for what I've tried.

If someone could provide a snippet of MASM source showing the definition of the root literal string, a string literal suffix, and how to use CATSTR (or @CatStr???) to define a new global symbol that contains the concatenation of the two strings, I would hope (fingers crossed!) to be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete working example that combines the string constant `"TABLE"` with a compile-time defined string named `SUFFIXB` and shows the result in a messagebox.

```
; ml /c /coff /DSUFFIXB=BETA test.asm
; link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS test.obj

.586p
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

ROOT textequ <TABLE>
msg CATSTR <">, ROOT, SUFFIXB, <">

.data
dlgmsg db msg,0
dlgtitle db "Title",0

.code
start:
invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, ADDR dlgmsg, ADDR dlgtitle, MB_OK 
invoke ExitProcess, NULL 

end start
```

---

As a side note, masm's `/EP` option can be useful when trying to figure out preprocessor syntax, as it allows you to see what your code looks like after it has gone through the preprocessor.